# chrome extension chrome.tabs.getCurrent fails, chrome.tabs.query({active: true} works in a normal script with activeTabs permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

A simple chrome extension that replaces the new tab

```
"permissions": ["activeTab"]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>_</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
let test = () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('imagen'))
}

chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, test)
chrome.tags.getCurrent(test)
```

These instructions should be equivalent (?)

Comment: 1) getCurrent() gets the tab where the code runs and since the popup is a separate page with its own URL (in a separate window with no tab) the result is useless, 2) content scripts can't use chrome.tabs API by definition (only a few limited APIs are available) so it's not a content script you have but a normal script loaded in an extension page (the popup in your case), 3) query() is the correct method but to ensure you get the current window's active tab you may want to add `currentWindow: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite positive that it's because you're calling chrome.ta***g***s instead of chrome.ta***b***s.

The documentation is also very clear that it won't work on background or popup pages but from your example I don't believe this is the case.

Comment: Jesus Christ, yes, it was a typo, and yes it wasn't a content script, I changed it in the definition but since this is a typo I'll delete the question (can't delete, nevermind), thousand thanks!